# How to save property after tombstoning?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, tombstoning

I have some property OwnerId that has each page in my application. I need these property to create HttpWebRequest and get some data. But when the application deactivated and activated again the page as deleted and created again, so these property is 0. I can't save these property in PhoneApplicationPage.State , because these property is different for different pages, so when I go twice back I can get error. I think to take it property after application activated from NavigationService.BackStack pages.But I'm not sure it is right. How can I do it ?

Comment: Aram -- Not sure if the question is very clear. Could you add some sample code?

Comment: Also, PhoneApplicationService.Current.State should be kept intact even on Tombstoning. Each page could have access to it's own State dictionary during OnNavigatedTo/OnNavigatedFrom.

Comment: @samidip Sorry for my bad English, I'll try  explain. Assume I have some page that displays info about user, I must have userId to show info about that user, this userId is my OwnerId, that have every page. When application deactivated my OwnerId become 0 so I can't show the information about user. I want to save the OwnerId for every instance of page that when application activated I can restore its value.

Comment: @samidip I know it, but for every instance of the page the value of OwnerId can be different, so I can't just store in PhoneApplicatonPage.State or PhoneApplicationService.Current.State

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aram .. thanks for explaining the question better.

Now, while your application is in the foreground, how are you managing all these different OwnerIDs? A collection? I am guessing you don't have multiple instances of the same page; but rather pass query parameters along to indicate which OwnerID/UserID should be used to display appropriate user info. You could put the whole collection in State dictionaries with a key & hydrate/dehydrate during the application lifecycle. Makes sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for trying help me. Sorry I don't understand you well. Every time I post some HttpWebRequest and from the response I get OwnerId. My application besides user info ,have photos, videos and other pages,and photo page also get user photos depends on OwnerId.

Comment: And I make requests to API, and I"ll want to do without query strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on whether you need a setting for each page or just a single setting for the app. In either case your best option (IMO) is IsolatedStorageSettings (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx)

If you just need a single setting then there's no problem but if you need one for each page you will need to do something ugly like using the page name as the key.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I'll try explain. Assume I have some page that displays info about user, I must have userId to show info about that user, this userId is my OwnerId, that have every page. When application deactivated my OwnerId become 0 so I can't show the information about user. I want to save the OwnerId for every instance of page that when application activated I can restore its value.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I would either do what samidip suggested in his answer or, if you need more control, serialize all of the IDs, pages etc. into XML (this allows you to add any information you may need and is easier to deal with when you need new information in a future update).

Comment: Please look at my comment on samidip answer. And thans for trying help me.

Comment: If you know the ownerId before you navigate to the page that consumes it then you should just put it in the query string for the page. Then you don't need to do anything at all. If you get the Id after the page is loaded then you could do something like add a unique number to the query string of each page (just increment an integer: ?pageId=23), you can then save a dictionary of pageIds and ownerIds when tombstoning. I really think that the query string is the easiest way to identify a page instance after tombstoning.

Comment: I get OwnerId after navigating, so I can't use query string. I think to keep a stack of OwnerId 's and every time I naveigate back, peek from the stack, and when I navigate from the page push to the stack. And save stack on PhoneApplicationServie.State. What do you think about this idea ?

Comment: It seems like a good system. Should be fine as a linear list of IDs corresponding to the pages in the back stack is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can I know the page url or take the page from the pages back stack? I don't need it, it's just interesting.

Comment: You can use the JournalEntry's in the BackStack: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394012(v=VS.92).aspx